# can't find tool named 'otool' in the macosx SDK or any fallback SDKs at ./symbolicatecrash line 115

Tags: ios, crash, ios9, crash-reports, dsym

I tried to analyse crash iOS app crash logs given by Apple store by using symbolicatecrash ~~~.crash and dSYM file.
However, when I tried to make crash.log, I got the following error. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

```
$ ./symbolicatecrash ~~~.crash ~~~.dSYM > crash.log

sh: ”/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer”/usr/bin/xcrun: No such file or directory
Error: can't find tool named 'otool' in the macosx SDK or any fallback SDKs at ./symbolicatecrash line 115.
```

The following is symbolicatecrash file

```
#symbolicatecrash
sub getToolPath {
    my ($toolName, $sdkGuess) = @_;

    if (!defined($sdkGuess)) {
        $sdkGuess = "macosx";
    }

    my $toolPath = `'$DEVELOPER_DIR/usr/bin/xcrun' -sdk $sdkGuess -find $toolName`;
    if (!defined($toolPath) || $? != 0) {
        if ($sdkGuess eq "macosx") {
            die "Error: can't find tool named '$toolName' in the $sdkGuess SDK or any fallback SDKs"; <------ This line is line115
        } elsif ($sdkGuess eq "iphoneos") {
            print STDERR "## Warning: can't find tool named '$toolName' in iOS SDK, falling back to searching the Mac OS X SDK\n";
            return getToolPath($toolName, "macosx");
        } else {
            print STDERR "## Warning: can't find tool named '$toolName' in the $sdkGuess SDK, falling back to searching the iOS SDK\n";
            return getToolPath($toolName, "iphoneos");
        }
    }

    chomp $toolPath;
    print STDERR "$toolName path is '$toolPath'\n" if $opt{v};

    return $toolPath;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've tried the same operation by bash( before I used zsh), then have gone well. It seems that the problem is cause from the setting of .zshrc.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more mate ? **I've tried the same operation by bash( before I used zsh),** I don't understand you said you have used zsh before..but how do I use that ?

Comment: Any help to let me know is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1)

Type this in at the command line:

`xcode-select --print-path`

If it shows the path of /Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer, then go to step 2.  If it doesn't, change the path using "`sudo xcode-select -s /path/to/your/Xcode/Contents/Developer`" folder.

2)

Try installing the Xcode command line tools which you can get under the "Additional Tools" link at http://developer.apple.com/xcode site.

3)

Make sure your .tcshrc / .bashrc "`$PATH`" environment variable is correct.  In my local machine "`xcrun`" lives in "`/usr/bin`" and `otool` lives in "`/usr/bin`" as well.

Comment: Thx Michael!
1)
$ xcode-select --print-path
”/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer”

2)
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

3)
$ which xcrun
/usr/bin/xcrun

$ which otool
/usr/bin/otool

In this case, should I update the Software(Xcode)?

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt.  We're up to Xcode 7.1 as of today.  Also, look at the error closely.  It's looking for an environment variable named "`$DEVELOPER_DIR`". It looks like it should be blank / empty, like it is on my machine (and then your "`/usr/bin/otool`" would resolve correctly for resymbolicating)..

Comment: Btw, I've set DEVELOPER_DIR as follows.

export DEVELOPER_DIR=”/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer”

Comment: doing that screws things up this line in your `symbolicatecrash ` script: `my $toolPath = `'$DEVELOPER_DIR/`.  Maybe you should modify your script?

Comment: I've tried the same operation by bash( before I used zsh), then have gone well!!!
Maybe, the problem of PATH of .zshrc

Comment: When I've found which point causes problem, let you know! Thank you:)

Comment: @lalala - "'ve tried the same operation by bash( before I used zsh), then have gone well!!! Maybe, the problem of PATH of .zshrc " can you please explain this step by step ... what is zsh and what is zshrc ? any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting DEVELOPER_DIR to "" worked
`$ export DEVELOPER_DIR=””`